# Not able to install dockerized Pact-broker on centos

Tags: docker, pact-broker

I'm trying to setup pact broker in centos machine using the instructions mentioned at https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker

I have installed docker and installed postgresql (not in docker container, but as separate service).

I tried running following command (bundled in https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker)

docker run --name pactbroker --link pactbroker-db:postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=pactbrokeruser -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=Thtest -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=pactbroker -d -p 80:80 dius/pact-broker

and i'm getting following message

Unable to find image 'dius/pact-broker:latest' locally
Pulling repository dius/pact-broker
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/dius/pact-broker/images: dial tcp 54.236.81.192:443: connection timed out

tried different mechanism like 
1. ran script/test.sh 
2. cd pact_broker-docker-master ; docker build .

still no luck.

More details :

## uname -a

Linux mock-tomcat-132867461-1-210308209 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 15 10:13:09 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux .

## cat /etc/*release

CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

Note: my machine is behind the company proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think your company's proxy is the issue. The relevant error message is:

```
Unable to find image 'dius/pact-broker:latest' locally
Pulling repository dius/pact-broker
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/dius/pact-broker/images: dial tcp 54.236.81.192:443: connection timed out
```

Try doing `docker pull dius/pact-broker:latest` and I'm guessing you'll see the same issue.

Perhaps [this blog post](https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-behind-a-proxy/) will help you debug your proxy issues. Good luck.